# How many mappings $\phi:\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}\to\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ exist such that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How many mappings $\phi:\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}\to\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ exist such that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$?

My book says that the answer is finite. However, I am getting infinite as the answer.
Let the prime numbers be mapped to any natural numbers of their choice of their choice, and let $0$ and $1$ map to $0$. Then numbers can be expressed in their prime factorization form, and be mapped to the corresponding sum.

For example, let us arbitrarily decide that $\phi(2)=3$ and $\phi(3)=7$. Then $\phi(2^43^2)=12+14=28$.

What is wring with this method?

Comment: For any number $n$, $\phi(n\times0) = \phi(0) = \phi(n)+\phi(0)$, so that $\phi(n)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @zarathustra: This is an answer. Not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any number $n$, we have $\phi(n)+\phi(0)=\phi(n\times 0) = \phi(0)$, i.e., $\phi(n)=0$. Therefore there is only one such function, which is identically $0$.